# First step with Google Apps Script: Can't call a function with two parameters

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, custom-function

In a Google Sheet, I want to get some stock market informations. I created this function:

```
function getPrice(sTicker, iColumn) {

  var iRow = 1;
  var response = ImportJSON("https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/company/profile/" + sTicker);  

  return response[iRow][1].toString().replace(".", ",");

}
```

I'm not even using the iColumn but in my Google Sheet, I got an error using '*=getPrice(B6,1)*'.

If I remove the second parameter when I call the function and I use '*=getPrice(B6)*' it works.

Someone can explain me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: the iColumn variable is not used inside your function, why do you need to include it?

Answer (score 1):

I just got it, the correct syntax is

*=getPrice(B6;1)*

and not

*=getPrice(B6,1)*

Comment: The first syntax works for you because your spreadsheet use comma as decimal separator, but if you change the regional setting  to one that use dot as decimal separator the second syntax will work.